# How can i add premium features in my app by in app purchases?

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

Let's say I have a list with 5 list items and I only want to offer 3 of those as free and I want to offer the rest as premium content. Free items are adding a note , adding 3 todos and bookmarks and premium features are like no ads and audio saving in my note app.

So my question is basically how can i add This feature like **if you pay few dollars the user is allowed to use those premium feature** or else watch 2 ads for 24hrs of free premium services i went through a ton of youtube video they are just telling me how to integrate in app purchases ok thats right but how can i add this premium features to that so that it will unlock once the payment is done. Simply adding text is not enough i guess

Comment: You can create a list of all users and those who have paid for premium. And when your app starts, check if the current user has paid for premium features; if not, then hide the paid features and show ads.

Answer (score 0):

You can check feature availability for free user and save how events user can perform, for example:

```dart
if (Purchase.isCompleted() || Preferences.featureLimitNotCharged()) {
  doAction();
} else {
  showPurchaseDialog();
}
```

If user watched an ads, you erase the limits from settings and user can be perform actions again, for example:

```dart
Preferences.eraseFeatureLimit();
```

Next time when user recharged feature limit, you show purchase dialog again.

Comment: Ookkk that clears a lot of things ... Thanks